# Compiling cmocka on windows

Tags: c, unit-testing

I'm trying to compile a simple unit test on my windows machine.
When I'm trying to compile my test I'm using the shared library flag.

```
gcc -c -L./bin/ -lcmocka .\Test.c .\src\some_module.c
gcc .\Test.o .\some_module.o -o main
```

But the second line throws this error:

```
undefined reference to `_cmocka_run_group_tests'
```

However, if I'm compiling using directly the cmocka.c file which I downloaded from their git it works fine:

```
gcc -c .\lib\cmocka.c .\Test.c .\src\some_module.c
gcc .\Test.o .\some_module.o .\cmocka.o
```

What am I doing wrong in the first compilation?
In addition, I would happy to understand the difference between the two compilations. Which one is the better practice?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe move the library to the end of the command line: `gcc -c -L./bin/ .\Test.c .\src\some_module.c -lcmocka`

Comment: No, didn't work..

Comment: My bad... you need the library only when compiling the final step (with the ".o" files): `gcc .\Test.o .\some_module.o -o main -lcmocka`

Answer (score 0):

In order to compile your code, the compiler does not need to know where to look for the library. It's enough if the compiler "finds" the declarations of the functions which are usually in the header files provided by the library.

This step is done in the first line of your compilation procedure (maybe you need to specify the folder to the header files by adding `-Ipath/to/headers/`):

```
gcc -c .\Test.c .\src\some_module.c
```

The library itself is "combined" with your code during the linking step, which is done during your second compilation step. Here you need to specify the library (and its path via `-Lpath/to/library`, if the linker does not find the library on its own):

```
gcc .\Test.o .\some_module.o -o main -L./bin/ -lcmocka
```

---

You should definitely not use your second approach and compile the library by yourself.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I'm trying to compile it in this order:
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcmocka

Comment: @RonyKositsky Have you changed `-L...` to point to the location of cmocka?

Comment: Yes, it points to the relevant path